# Hidden XPATH to find element of text? Ruby-selenium

Tags: ruby, xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find the xpath of the element below, so that I can later get the text using Ruby Selenium-webdriver (ie. `helloPage.mainHeader.get_text`).

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="template-section">
    <div class="front">
      <h3 class="containerHeading">
      <i class="icon_image"></i>
      "Hello world   <-----------------------3 whitespaces
      "
      </h3>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I've worked on xpaths but everytime I rerun the test it timesout essentially the element does not exist. It is clearly visible on the UI and not hidden.

Why is my xpath is wrong? I have tried the following:

1. `//div[@class='container']//div[@class='template-section']//div[@class='front']//h3[@class='containerHeading']`
2. `//div[@class='front']//h3[@class='containerHeading']`
3. `//h3[@class='containerHeading']`

I did put sleep prior to executing `helloPage.mainHeader.get_text`, where `mainHeader` has the XPath expression, and that didn't work. Is there something mysterious about the Hello World text? The format is indeed like the way I typed it out.

Comment: Looking at the `xpaths` you have provided they are all valid. However, for 'A' you could rewrite it as `//div[@class='container']/div[@class='template-section']/div[@class='front']/h3[@class='containerHeading']`, note the single fore-slashes separating the elements. So are you seeing an error or exception when you try to find the element? Have you used another tool to check that your `xpath` is valid as well?

Comment: Use Firefox with firepath to test your xpath. Also, just as an experiment, change [@class='foo'] to [contains(@class, 'foo')].

Comment: @Mark Rowlands - Yes, I am getting errors when I used your provided xpath. Instead, I change it to: //div[@class='container']//div[@class='template-section']/div[@class='front']/h3‌​[@class='containerHeading'] , then it is a valid xpath. Note that there are // on template-section

The value of the xpath returns blank when I try to get the text.

Comment: @RobbieWareham - Yes, I have been using Chrome extensions (xPath Viewer, and XPath Helper) to check things. As an experiment I did try: //div[contains(@class, 'container')]/div[contains(@class,'template-section')]/div[contains(@class, 'front')]/h3[contains(@class, 'containerHeading')]

As a result, I am still getting nothing back as text

Comment: You had to include the double-fore-slash? Strange. That notation means 'find any of the following'. So you're, in effect, saying "find me any div with the class 'container', and in that find me any div with the class 'template-section', and inside that fine me any div with the class 'front'... etc". Perhaps this is a Ruby thing? Sorry, I'm a Python user. As asked before, have you tried any tools to help validate/build your 'xpath'? Are the 'elements' you want to interact with inside an 'iframe' perhaps?

Comment: "nothing back" as in no text or element not found? If you get the element but no text, then try "get_attribute('innerText')" rather than get_text

Comment: Apparently, I found out that my app dynamically loads all the DOM elements ahead of time, all those fancy AJAX animation stuff. So when I click and go to the next page and look for the particular header text, it doesn't appear. The workaround I have is by doing a browser refresh and then I am able to find the xpath and get text. It isn't ideal but as a temporary fix.

Answer (score 0):

all your xpaths seems correct to me... I think when you are trying to find the element using your xpath ... the element is not loaded properly... try to use explicit wait. Please try to use the code provided below:

```
    wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)
    wait.until { driver.find_elements(:xpath, "Any of your above mentioned xpaths") }
```